# "How many rooms left to clean?"

Tags: grammaticality

I want to express how many rooms have yet to be cleaned before the work is finished. Is this correct:

> How many rooms left to clean?

Comment: You are missing a verb. **Left** in this sentence is not a verb, as is **leave/left**. At least, your sentence needs a verb: *How many rooms* **are** *left to clean?* There are still better ways to ask, but that's a major miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is grammatically incorrect. A better way to say this would be: **How many rooms are yet to be cleaned?**